# KeyAlgorithm for SHA256

Tags: .net, powershell, msdn, x509certificate2

The [PowerShell command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633.aspx) below creates a self-signed certificate with SHA1 as signature algorithm.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "MyCertificate", "www.contoso.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Provider "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider"
```

[image: MyCertificate]

Is there any value that I can pass to this command (for example: `-KeyAlgorithm`) to make the certificate generated using SHA256 as signature algorithm?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`KeyAlgorithm` parameter defines the public key algorithm which is not related to signature algorithm (what you are trying to accomplish). Instead, you need to use `-HashAlgorithm` parameter and specify `SHA256` as a parameter value:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "MyCertificate", "www.contoso.com" `
    -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" `
    -Provider "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" `
    -HashAlgorithm "SHA256"
```